# Use clipping or zero padding

Tags: python

Write a function that accept an array of N elements, and converts it into a 9-element array. Use clipping or zero padding to obtain the desired output. Care should be taken to place the middle element of the input array as the middle element of output array.

Examples

```
A = [ 2, 5, 1 ] # N == 3, so zero padding to make the output size 9
output = [0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0]

A = [ 2, 3, 7, 4 ]
output = [0, 0, 2, 3, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0]  or [0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 7, 4, 0, 0] # Because there are two middle elements if N is even

A = [ 1, 3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 ]  # N == 13, so remove 4 elements (2 at the right, 2 at the left) to make the output size 9
output = [3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2]

A = [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 ]
output = [3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2] or [3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you want an output list of `n=9` with zeros padding and an input list `A`.

Then treat the thing as separate problems:

1. If `len(A) == n` return `A`
2. If `len(A) > n` then return the middle `n` elements of `A`.
3. Else return a list that starts with `(n - len(A)) // 2` zeros, then `A`, then ends with `n - (n - len(A)) // 2 - len(A)` zeros (however much is left over from `n` elements).

E.g.

```
def fulllist(A, n):
  if len(A) == n:
    return A
  if len(A) > n:
    start = (len(A) - n) // 2
    return A[start:start+n]
  if len(A) < n:
    leftpad  = [0] * ((n - len(A)) // 2)
    rightpad = [0] * (n - len(leftpad) - len(A))
    return leftpad + A + rightpad
```

This gives the following as output:

```
>>> fulllist([2, 5, 1], 9)
[0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>>> fulllist([2, 3, 7, 4], 9)
[0, 0, 2, 3, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0]
>>> fulllist([1, 3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1], 9)
[3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2]
>>> fulllist([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1], 9)
[3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2]
```

The above function was written to match the pseudocode, but it would be better to alter it slightly, eliminating case 1. by treating it as a special case of 2. or 3.. That way the code is shorter, and more important, the function always returns a brand new list in every case instead of sometimes returning a reference to the input list, which could get confused in subsequent code and lead to some bugs. I chose to merge 1. with 2.

```
def fulllist(A, n):
  if len(A) >= n:
    start = (len(A) - n) // 2
    return A[start:start+n]
  else:
    leftpad  = [0] * ((n - len(A)) // 2)
    rightpad = [0] * (n - len(leftpad) - len(A))
    return leftpad + A + rightpad
```

Or you can shorten the code further by abusing the fact that `[0] * -1 == []`.

```
def fulllist(A, n):
  leftpad  = [0] * ((n - len(A)) // 2)
  rightpad = [0] * (n - len(leftpad) - len(A))
  start    = (len(A) - n) // 2 if len(A) > n else 0
  contents = A[start:start+n]

  return leftpad + contents + rightpad
```

Although that may be going too far for some and it might make the code harder to understand. I like it though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
def padding(arr,n):
    diff = abs(n - len(arr))
    start, end = int(diff / 2), diff - int(diff / 2)
    if len(arr) < n:
        for i in range(start):
            arr.insert(0,0)
        for i in range(end):
            arr.append(0)
    else:
        for i in range(start):
            arr.pop(0)
        for i in range(end):
            arr.pop(-1)
    return arr

A = [ 1, 3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 ]
print(padding(A,9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
def padding(l1):
    flag = 0
    while len(l1)>=9:
        if len(l1) == 9:
            return l1
        if flag %2== 0:
            l1.pop()
        else:
            l1.pop(0)
        flag+=1
    if len(l1)<9:
        iterations = (9- len(l1))//2
        for _ in range(iterations):
            l1.insert(0,0)
            l1.append(0)
        if iterations % 2 == 0:
            l1.append(0)
    return l1

padding(A)
```